# Cartoon about the son of a blacksmith who made friends with a warrior and an archer, and fought monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

When I was younger, around 2015-2016, I used to watch a cartoon.

It was about a boy who had an old father who was a blacksmith. That boy I think had a blue jacket on and he could teleport. He made a friend group with a magic girl archer and a warrior who could transform into like a black warrior.

I remember an episode that that warrior was with his master. He had to fight a giant monster but he couldn't. His master told him that he needs to '*use his head*' and he literally started hitting the giant with his head and defeated him.

Comment: Where were you younger? Was this in English? Did it look like Japanese animation? Western animation? Shockwave Flash? What was the ethnicity and hair color of the boy and the people he fought with?

Comment: What country were you living in? Do you know what network it might have run on, or other cartoons running at the same time? Given the target was a giant, was the warrior headbutting his knees? Jumping to hit it with his head? Was the boy's teleportation skill magic? Just moving really fast? Using a matter transporter to deconstruct himself and reconstruct at another location? Was this a medieval setting? Modern day? Futuristic?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I live in Serbia, idk about the program that run the show, it might be a program called Ultra, a TV channel in Serbia but I seriously don't know. The animation wasn't Japanese. The boy didn't run really fast or anything similar, he could straight up teleport, I think he had white od yellow hair, the medivak setting I think was like magic-futuristic. He fought like some really weird people. That warrior just jumped on a gaint, they were in desert, and he just started hitting him with his head. That's all I know. I would really be thankful if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently when did you watch the show? 1980s? 2000s? Five years ago?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I would say probably like 2015-2016.

Comment: See if something here rings a bell. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UseYourHead  "Blue Exorcist" looks promising. Also "Blood Blockade Battlefront"

Answer (score 5):

With the exception of being a son of a blacksmith, what you're describing is [**Wakfu**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu_(TV_series)).

First released in 2008, but they were making episodes in 2017, so within your timeframe (the episode you specifically remember was originally aired in France in 2010). Mainly produced in France and the Serbian channel you mentioned did appear to have a fair bit of French animation on it.

[image: wakfu]

The guy in the middle there is Yugo, he seems to fit your description visually and has the power to create transportation portals. He's not the son of a blacksmith.

Far left we have Evangelyne who is an archer who can fire a variety of magical arrows.

Second from left is Sir Percedal. His sword is possessed by a Shushu (think demon) called Rubilax which has possessed him in the past. There are various degrees to which Rubilax transforms Percedal's body:

[image: arm possessed]

[image: fully possessed]

Here is what Rubilax is like in his own body:
[image]

The episode where Percedal meets his old master and defeats a monster (actually a free Rubilax) by 'using his head' is Season 1 Episode 22 titled 'Rubilax'. Description:

> Percedal flees to the desert, close to the tomb of his former master,
> who is surprisingly still alive.

Comment: Sidenote: another French fantasy animation which dealt with wondering kids with powers was Lanfuest Quest. Otherwise quite different from Wakfu, but the mc was the son of a blacksmith, so perhaps these two cartoons are crossed in OPs memory.

Comment: @K Mo BRO WERE YOU THE ONE TO ANSWER MY QUESTION? I CAN'T SEE YOUR USERNAME, IF YOU DID, BROOOO THANKK YOU SO MUCH. OMG I CAN'T BELIEVE I FINALLY FOUND IT YESSSSS. BRO I AM SO THANKFUL. THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: @ K Mo MAN THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCHHHHHHHH

Comment: @LazarGrujic mark the answer as correct please.